# Array Best Match

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

You have been called upon to write a Match-Making program for a marriage beaureau. The beaureau’s questionnaire has 8 statements, and the applicant indicates her or his degree of agreement on a scale of 1 to 5. The response of the applicant is entered through the keyboard. Each response contains the applicant’s code number, sex (F or M), & response to the questionnaire (8 integers). 
You may assume that there are no more than 50 applicants. Your program should match each person with 3 most compatible person of opposite sex and should print the code no. of applicant along with code no. of prospective applicants.

i want to implement this through c++. Is there any matching algorithm for this ?. or there is some simple approach. It would be nice for me, if you write the whole function.

and sorry, if the question is very simple bcs i'm a learner.

Comment: If you want a C++ implementation, why use the C tag? C != C++.

Comment: Start a little coding yourself. For instance - declare the array. Try iterating it. Just something... then we can help. You don't learn by having us doing your homework. You learn by trying and failing. And then being helped by someone pointing out the failure. Good luck.

Comment: @nielsen: k..i'll implement it myself. but can u pls share the logic.

Comment: Not sure I am following - are you looking for the "closest" element in the array to a given input element `x`? This can be done easily using linear scan, or if your array is already sorted using binary search.

Comment: @m0rphes: ok - just a little start-up help. `int arr[5] = {3, 7, 12, 5, 9}; int i, diff = -1; for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {....};` The function abs() could be useful! Does this help?

Comment: @amit: As I understand the question, it is just a matter of finding the element that has the lowest numerical distance to the first element. Not anything complicated.

Comment: @nielsen: thnx for replying..but i need more help !! actually this is really a 'hw' ques..nd i've completed it 80%..so, i need a little help, i've edited the ques. for u to better understand the situation. pls ve a look at it.

Comment: @nielsen: i've completed the whole ques nd just wanna know a suitable matching algorithm. even i tried for okcupid's matching algo..but failed..that's why i wanna know the whole code .

Comment: @m0rphes: Post the code you have so far - then we can guide you

Comment: @nielsen: i guess the whole code is very big to be posted as comment. i just wanna know the logic of matching algo. so, can u pls explain it.

Comment: @m0rphes: ok, I'll post an answer to get you going...

Comment: @nielsen: thnx.. :) nd waiting !!

Comment: Wow... I wish there was SO when I was at uni...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner copy pasted his uni homework and seems not to have a clue what he needs to do. He wants a full implementation so that he can turn it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comments above I'll post some comments to get you started. But remember the best thing is to try something on your own and then get help afterwards...

```
int questionnaire_answers[50][8]; // 2D array holding answers
int sex[50];                      // 1D array holding sex of those who answered

int i, j;
int index = 0;
int best = 999999;
int distance;

// We look for the best match for the first person
for (i = 1; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (sex[0] != sex[i])
    {
       // Calculate the distance from index 0 to index i
       // See note below
       distance = 0;
       for (j=0 ; j < 8; j++)
       {
          distance = distance + abs(questionnaire_answers[0][j]-questionnaire_answers[i][j]);
       }
    }
    else
    {
       distance = 999999;
    }
    if (distance < best)
    {
       best = distance;
       index = i;
    }
}

// Now index holds the index of the best match
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to find the second and third best match :)

IMPORTANT:
I have used a simple linear distance calculation. In the real world you will probably do better with something more complicated. The world of math has several good option, e.g. least/minimum-mean-square

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cosine Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). First normalize the 50X8 matrix such that each column has mean=0 and standard deviation=1. Now for each record(row), calculate the cosine correlation with every other record. The record giving maximum cosine correlation will be a match for this record.